# Is 'beim spielen' correct?

Tags: grammar-identification

While looking for a translation for "while playing", I ran across many examples of "beim spielen":

> Sie haben die letzte Zeit ein Menge Zeit **beim spielen** eines Fantasiespiels namens Prometheus verbracht.

> **Beim spielen** ging es sich immer um die Mutter.

and even:

> Er rennt sie **beim spiel** um, sie geben ihm einen besen.

These examples can be found here: https://bit.ly/41rYlHh

and one example of:

> Mutter-Jungtier-Interaktionen sind ansonsten nur selten dokumentiert, sie beschränken sich auf das Säugen und auf Schutz seitens der Mutter, **während spielen** oder gegenseitige Körperpflege bisher nicht beobachtet wurde.

How is this correct? Why is the participle not being used? Are these typos that should be capitalized?

Comment: There are a lot of examples for "beim Spielen", see for example https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/beim+Spielen

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify.

Comment: The DWDS corpus you linked is "Blogs" (web-based corpus) so there is a high likelihood that people make spelling mistakes or don't capitalize at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these typos that should be capitalized?

Yes.

> How is this correct? Why is the participle not being used?

Because we don't use the Partizip I for progressive and continous aspects in German. And neither for gerunds. German has no aspects nor a gerund.

That form *beim Spielen* is a modal adverbial that uses a nominalized infinitive as an argument to the preposition *bei*. A modal adverbial tells a circumstance. You could also use a normal noun as in the example *beim Spiel*. The latter is common when someone wants to describe a concept rather than an action as the circumstance.

> Beim Füttern von Löwen …

This is more about the action of feeding lions. How the zookeper would explain it. Hands on. Or better not.

> Bei der Fütterung von Löwen …

That's more about the concept of feeding lions. How an expert on lions would explain it. About nutrition, ranks of the lions, and so on.

> während Spielen oder gegenseitige Körperpflege

Don't let this fool you. That *während* does not translate to English *while* in the temporal sense. It translates into *whereas*!

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks.